# How to upgrade PHP version and MySQL to the latest stable released version?

Tags: php, mysql, debian, google-cloud-platform, upgrade

I'm using google computer engine running on Debian GNU/Linux 8 with PHP version 5.6.30-0 and MySQL version 5.5.54 installed.

I would to upgrade my PHP software to v7 and mysql to v5.6.

I tried the following command, but it isn't working:

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade

    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

any ideas?

Comment: And what does "but it is not working" actually mean?

Comment: not working  means nothing is updated , still PHP version 5.6.30-0

Comment: I bet that those commands did not silently finish leaving your installed packages unchanged. I would expect some error they report if they fail...

Comment: thanks , i don't know much about linux command , the first command did update something, but when i use php -v to check,  sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found

Comment: thanks , i don't know much about linux command . the first command did update something, but when i use php -v to check, it is showing the same things. then i follow this tutorial from digital ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04    using "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php" it shows sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found.   the first command output forgot to save.

Comment: `/usr/bin/apt-add-repository` is part of the `software-properties-common` package. If it does not exist, then either your PATH variable has an exotic setting or it (that package) is not installed.

Comment: `php -v` checks the version of the CLI flavor of PHP, not sure if that is what you are interested in.